# What is the counting sequence of a Binary String?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a two part question dealing with the binary strings for Discrete Math and I am stuck on the meaning of the very last part.

(a) List all binary strings of length 3.

- Since a binary string is just a sequence of 0 and 1s I got the answer: **2x2x2 or 2^3**

(b) What is the counting sequence of binary strings?

- I want to say **permutations or "arrangement type counting sequence"**, but I think the answer expects a mathematical response or generalization. Can someone show me how to correctly answer this question?

Comment: For a) they want a list.  For b) maybe the geometric sequence of powers of $2$.

Comment: The first one wanted a list, but I ended up just typing the # of possible strings since I was lazy and by geometric sequence do you mean something such as 2^n where n is the number of possible slots for a bit?

Comment: You could say that the number $a_n$ of $n$-bit words is given by the geometric sequence $a_n=2^n$.  By the way this  even works for $n=0$: there is one word of length $0$.